# How to know if IRazorPage is a partial view in IRazorPageActivator.Activate

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

Is there anyway to identify if the IRazorPage is a main page, a partial or the actual layout in a custom IRazorPageActivator?

The only object you have is the IRazorPage and ViewContext and I've searched alot but can't find any clues to the above info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I actually found a solution, but not sure if it's "hacky" or not :)
Im using the UrlHelpers ViewContext that will be the parent ViewContext and possible to compare ExecutingFilePath with context.View.Path that will only be equal for the actual page (not partials) and therefor possible to filter out partials!

Needs more testing...

```
public void Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
{
    ViewContext viewContext = null;

    if(context.HttpContext.Items.TryGetValue(typeof(IUrlHelper), out var urlHelper) && urlHelper is IUrlHelper)
    {
        viewContext = (ViewContext)((IUrlHelper)urlHelper).ActionContext;
    }

    viewContext = viewContext ?? context;

    // Will only set Layout for the actual page view and only if not allready set
    if(viewContext.ExecutingFilePath.Equals(context.View.Path, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && page.Layout == null)
    {
        page.Layout = "_SpecialLayout";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t really much you can use to figure this out. What you *could* do is look at `page.Path` and `context.View.Path`. If those are equal, then you are rendering an actual view (instead of a layout or view imports). The former will contain the path to the current view being rendered (e.g. the layout), while the latter will just contain the path to the actual view being rendered (e.g. `Index.cshtml`).

For partials however, both of these will still be equal, so you won’t be able to identify partials that way. What you could do there is check out `page.Layout`. This will *usually* be `null` for partials.

But there won’t be a safe way to identify these as the razor page activator simply isn’t supposed to care about them.

Comment: So where is the ”closest” in the chain from the activator where you have access to this info and how?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im actually trying to solve several things, but the must important is to programatically set the Layout for full views where this is not set (making it hard to look at an empty Layout property :) Ive looked at several possibilities in the chain but no one seems suitable, so maybe its just has to be done in the view / viewstart file...

Comment: Usually, for setting the default layout, that’s exactly what you would use the `_ViewStart.cshtml` for. It will be executed before any view, so unless a view actually sets a layout explicitly itself, the configured layout from the `_ViewStart.cshtml` will be used.

Comment: Yes I know :) but this is special case with a tool / framework I’m developing and it would be nice to do that for the developer since it involves some logic...

Comment: Think I found a solution. Do you know if there is a better way to get the "original" ViewContext than thru UrlHelper?